# Explanation of 'elif' in Mouse as paint brush code

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

OpenCV-Python 3.4.1
IDE - PyCharm

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

events = [i for i in dir(cv) if 'EVENT' in i]
print(events)

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
global ix,iy,drawing,mode
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y
    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
            else:
                cv.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)
    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:  # this part start
            cv.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        else:
            cv.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1) # this part end

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv.namedWindow('image')
cv.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)
while(1):
    cv.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
        mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to understand the OpenCV-Python code for using Mouse as paint brush.

Link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html

Now, I have the following questions:

1. What is the need of `elif` in function `elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE`: ?
   I mean why can't we use `if` instead of `elif`? I don't get why we use 
   `elif`.
2. What is the use of

   ```
   if mode == True:
       cv.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
   else:
       cv.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)
   ```

I mean the 'this part' in the code?

I tried to understand it but I couldn't. 
Please help.

Comment: @Jeru Luke how did you edit the second question and put it in the code format? I tried with 4 spaces but couldn't do it.

Comment: actually I did it, it seems that it needed more spaces because it is inside the numbering... @JeruLuke fix the extra indentation in the else that i missed :)

Comment: @api55 Ach so!! ok thanks :) could you please answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can use `if` instead of `elif` in this case, since they are mutually exclusive. Either the event is this or that, but `elif` is probably used to avoid checking both `if` conditions every time. In C++ you could use switch, but as far as I know there is no switch in python.
2. Mode seems to change from rectangle shape to circle shape in your selection. You may use `m` to change from one mode to the other one.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not clear. Look at the first if. It says if left mouse button pressed then set drawing to True. Then it should be if mouse move then check mode. Because we need both ifs for drawing so elif doesn't seem right here. 
And for the second question, I meant if we close the drawing if the left mouse button is up, then why do we need to check the mode again?

Do you get my question?

Comment: @Winbuntu You can't have both events in one call to this callback. Either event is equal to mouse down or to mouse move, in the next call if you still have the button down, it will not have button down event, that only happens once every click (even if you still have the button down) and then if you move the mouse the event will be move the mouse. Finally you release the button and you get the button up event ONLY

Comment: Thanks. The first question is solved but the second question? why do we need to check the mode and draw rectangle or circle accordingly even after we get the button up event after releasing the button?

Comment: @Winbuntu This one I think it is not necessary. I suppose it is making sure it has the latest values... nevetherless, the code you give uses a lot of globals, the variables to use should be passed in the params argument.... every circle/rectangle is drawn in the same image, if you try to make it smaller probably it will be always big....

Comment: okay. Maybe it is to retain the latest value but it is still unclear and not so easy to understand. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @Winbuntu BTW, if it was me, I would do a class with all this global parameters, and pass it via the callback (in out variable) and then draw only in the loop and not in every callback, this will only draw every time it is refreshed and also you may draw on a copy of the image and avoid drawing over one single image, in case you want to reduce the size

Comment: Thanks. That's better.